# VS2013: STL regex class crashes when regular expression contains \

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a small C++ program to search and replace strings in numerous files; for example, to search for:

```
0x6e }
```

Here is my regular expression:

```
regex regex1("0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}\s\}");
```

and it crashes at the above line.

The regular expression works when using Notepad++.

Please advise on how to handle the `}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Escape the `\`**

Changing the regex to the following will get it to work;

```
regex regex1("0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}\\s\\}");
//                              ^  ^  additional escaping
```

The same character, `\`, is used as the escape character in C++ and the regex. The single `\` starts the C++ character escape (the compiler should at least warn on the invalid ones). A double `\\` will be parsed to give the `regex` the escape character it needs.

**Raw string literals**

Consider using the C++ [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), introduced in C++11 (no escaping required). Something like this should do the trick;

```
regex regex1(R"(0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}\s\})");
```

The C++ raw string literals are of the form;

> R"*delimiter*(raw_character*)*delimiter*"

Where the *delimiter* is optional and the `raw_character*` string must not contain the terminating sequence `)delimiter"`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remember that `\` is not only the escape character for regular expressions, but also the escape character for string literals. To produce a `\` character as an escape character in the regexp, rather than the string, you need to escape it: `\\`. Alternatively, if your compiler supports c++11, you can use the raw string literal: `R"(0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}\s\})"`